# My android app is working properly in debug mode in android studio but not working when i install from google playstore

Tags: android, google-play, proguard

Can anybody help me in proguard-rules.pro, Yesterday my app was working fine when i downloaded from google playstore. but when i updated my app with proguard-rules my app crashes when i download from google play store. but runs perfectly when i run from android studio in debug mode.

I have currently updated my proguard-rules.pro

```
    -keep class com.squareup.okhttp.** { *; }
    -keep class retrofit.** { *; }
    -keep interface com.squareup.okhttp.** { *; }

    -dontwarn com.squareup.okhttp.** 
    -dontwarn okio.**
    -dontwarn retrofit.**
    -dontwarn rx.**
    -dontwarn okio.**
    -dontwarn retrofit2.**
    -keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    @retrofit.http.* <methods>;
    }
```

---

and I have these many libraries in my gradle file

```
compile "com.android.support:support-v4:$SUPPORT_LIBRARY_VERSION"
compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$SUPPORT_LIBRARY_VERSION"
compile "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:$SUPPORT_LIBRARY_VERSION"
compile "com.android.support:cardview-v7:$SUPPORT_LIBRARY_VERSION"
compile "com.android.support:design:$SUPPORT_LIBRARY_VERSION"
compile "com.android.support:support-annotations:$SUPPORT_LIBRARY_VERSION"

compile "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:$RETROFIT_VERSION"
compile "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:$RETROFIT_VERSION"
compile "com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava:$RETROFIT_VERSION"
compile "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:$OKHTTP_VERSION"
compile "com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:$OKHTTP_VERSION"

compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.2.1'
compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.3.0'
compile 'com.jakewharton.timber:timber:4.1.1'

compile "com.jakewharton:butterknife:$BUTTERKNIFE_VERSION"
annotationProcessor "com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:$BUTTERKNIFE_VERSION"

compile "com.google.dagger:dagger:$DAGGER_VERSION"
annotationProcessor "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:$DAGGER_VERSION"
provided 'javax.annotation:jsr250-api:1.0'
compile 'javax.inject:javax.inject:1'

implementation("com.mikepenz:materialdrawer:6.0.6@aar") {
    transitive = true
}

compile 'com.github.javiersantos:AppUpdater:2.0.2'
compile 'com.thoughtbot:expandablerecyclerview:1.0'

implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.3.1'
annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.3.1'

compile 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:[3.7.1, 3.99.99]'

compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.3.2'
compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
compile 'com.daimajia.slider:library:1.1.5@aar'
compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.1@aar') {
    transitive = true;
}
```

But I am getting an error and I really don't know what is happening

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
at f.d.c.g.run (Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:428)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run (FutureTask.java:237)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run (ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:272)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:762)
Caused by: java.lang.InternalError: 
at f.d.e.b.y.a (Unknown Source)
at f.d.e.b.r.<clinit> (Unknown Source)
at f.d.a.n$a.<init> (Unknown Source)
at f.d.a.n.a (Unknown Source)
at f.d.a.n.a (Unknown Source)
at f.d.a.f.a (Unknown Source)
at f.d.a.f.a (Unknown Source)
at f.e.a (Unknown Source)
at f.d.a.p$a.a (Unknown Source)
at f.d.c.a$b$1.a (Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: 
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredField (Native Method)
```

My gradle (app)

```
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 9
    versionName "1.6"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    javaCompileOptions {
        annotationProcessorOptions {
            includeCompileClasspath false
        }
    }

}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

[image: Image from google play console.]

Comment: You should use retrace, or upload your mapping file to the console, so that you can deobsfucate your stacktrace.

Comment: how can i get  or generate the mapping file?

Answer (score 0):

It's difficut to find the error with `a.b.c.d.e.f..`

By default, in `AndroidStudio 3`, when you build a released application, there is a mapping file which helps any analysis service like `FirebaseAnalysis` or `Crashlytic` can detect where the error is and give you as much context and detail as possible when runtime exceptions occur.

Upload the mapping file which located at `build/outputs/mapping/release/mapping.txt` to Proguard Deobfuscation in your `Google Play Console`. Then track the error again.

Comment: i uploaded the file but still can't get crash in a readable format.

Comment: Do I need to wait? after uploading the file.

Comment: It takes some time to upload and execute the file. Please check the top-right bar.

Comment: Old logs won't be deobfuscated. You have to do it yourself using the proguard gui. You can find it in your Android SDK

Comment: Absolutely. You need to track new log and wait for the same error to see what happen. (IllegalStateException->InternalError-> NoSuchFieldException)